# Profit Maximisation for a Monopolist

Tags: monopoly

Suppose a monopolist faces the following inverse demand function : 
$p = exp(-Q)$
The monopolist can produce any positive level of output with zero variable cost. Its fixed cost is $F$. Find the profit-maximising output for two cases (i) when $F = 0.1$ and (ii) when $F= 0.5$.
I tried solving it using, $MR=MC$, the latter in this case is zero, so in both the cases I am getting 1 as the answer, and I am not sure if it is correct!

Comment: Your answer is correct. The profit-maximizing price and quantity are independent of fixed cost as fixed cost does not appear in the first-order condition. In the former case, profit is positve, while the latter corresponds to negative profit.

Comment: Can you describe the cost function? Is it  $C(q) = F$  OR  $C(q) = \begin{cases} F & \text{if } Q > 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } Q = 0 \end{cases}$ ?

Comment: @Amit they haven't mentioned the cost function specifically, but since the variable cost is zero I think the former is the right interpretation!

Comment: @dlnB how did you arrive at the conclusion that the profit is negative in the second case without plotting the graph?